# Appendix in research paper?

Tags: publications, citations

Should I include an appendix before or after the reference for my course physics project?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Appendices usually come before the bibliography (as you may need to cite things in the appendices). It's worth checking if your university has its own style guide, just in case.

Comment: At least in my field appendices always appear *after* the bibliography.

Comment: The OP is asking about physics; I'm a physicist.